# What is a reasonable size for a javascript object

Tags: javascript, memory, client

I have a client tree model that will store key (numbers) and value (string - average 60 character length) values. At its max the tree may have up to 2500 nodes. - This seems to be too large of an object to keep in memory (around 290kb), so I'm going to  load the nodes on demand and cache some of them .

My question is  - what is a reasonable object size in javascript that I could keep in memory? I realize that it would largely depend on what else is going on on the page, but would still like to hear opinions of a good size for a cache object like my tree

Comment: My browser usually runs at about 500mb of mem. usage with my normal load of tabs open.  I don't really see 290k being a problem.

Comment: Do you really need to store these values? 290KB of size may not be the problem. The problem is what you'll do with this object. It depends on your public, but you could store values in LocalStorage (IE8+).

Comment: @EliseuMonar - thought about Local Storage, but unfortunately we need to support IE7 as well

Comment: Yes, you need, but you could use progressive enhancement. If the browser supports some way of local storage, we use it, otherwise we get the object via XHR (AJAX). IE7 users are used to browse slowly, and they are about 3% of the marketshare, so don't worry that much...

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume, based upon the size of the data you are trying to store, that you are using this data in some kind of client-side processing. You might be displaying it in a tabular format, or using it as part of a search or sorting process.

When designing a data-driven site; processing-heavy operations should remain on the server-side, where it can be optimised, cached and processed faster by your server software or database manager.

The optimum size in this case varies so heavily that I doubt there is any single objective answer. I believe a number of browsers, particularly mobile browsers, have memory restrictions that prevent the entire device being rendered unstable by memory-hogging JavaScript. This memory restriction is probably very high, but it should be treated only as a fail-safe, not as the allowable upper-limit of memory you're allowed to use.

I highly recommend you re-evaluate the purpose of your JavaScript object and see whether the same thing can be accomplished server-side (maybe delivered in pieces, by AJAX, as it is required). This will reduce client-side processing overhead, bandwidth usage, and generally result in a more stable and responsive user-experience.

Comment: The object I'm trying to cache will be used in several location on the page. One being auto-complete for a text field, and the other being a multi select type of list (the data is a tree data structure, and so the list will have multiple levels of possible selection). The data is pretty static, and a user may stay on a page for a while working with our app. That's why I'd like to keep that data on the client (or at least part of the data) rather then make many server trips. Is there a good reference place to see what the memory restrictions for the different browsers are ?